# What identifier rules do I need to adhere to when using AddSubType?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I've defined the following inheritance hierarchy using protobuf-net and its `RuntimeTypeModel`

```
var model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();

model.Add(typeof(LineFields), false)
    .Add(1, nameof(LineFields.Length))
    .UseConstructor = false;

model.Add(typeof(ArcFields), false)
    .Add(1, nameof(ArcFields.Length))
    .Add(2, nameof(ArcFields.Curvature))
    .UseConstructor = false;

model.Add(typeof(GeometryFields), false)
    .AddSubType(1, typeof(LineFields))
    .AddSubType(2, typeof(ArcFields));
```

My tests appear to pass but I'm somewhat uneasy about the identifiers used for the above `AddSubType` identifiers. Should these identifiers be different from any identifiers used in the sub-types?, i.e. should I rather be doing:

```
model.Add(typeof(GeometryFields), false)
    .AddSubType(101, typeof(LineFields))
    .AddSubType(102, typeof(ArcFields));
```

(is the `AddSubType` effectively doing the same as the `ProtoInclude` attribute as described [here](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net?tab=readme-ov-file#inheritance)?)

Comment: Okay, so I think the last comment by @MarcGravell here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29283215/1501327 defines the behaviour, i.e., the above is similar to the 'X' and 'Y' classes in the comment and as such should have a different value to any identifiers that may be used in `GeometryFields` above (there are currently no fields defined for the `GeometryFields` base class, so pretty sure the original is fine, although I may opt for the '101', '102' variant to define sub-types as opposed to direct properties.