# protobuf-net : how to annotate properties of derived type?

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

For the latest version of `protobuf-net` ( `r640` folder ), how to best annotate a `ProtoMember` that is a derived type ?

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"MyBaseTypeProto")]                                       
[Serializable]      
public partial class MyBaseType: ProtoBuf.IExtensible { ... }

[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"MyDerivedTypeProto")]                                        
[Serializable]      
public partial class MyDerivedType : MyBaseType, ProtoBuf.IExtensible { ... }

[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"MyMessageProto")]                                                
[Serializable]                                                                                  
public partial class MyMessage : ProtoBuf.IExtensible                                           
{                                                                                               
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name = @"MyList", DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(null)]                                                  
    public List<MyDerivedType> MyList;
```

I've tried adding `DynamicType` property to the `ProtoMember` attribute but it's not recognized.

I require a solution where the classes can be generated from `xml defs` of `proto types`.  So ideally this would be done via attributes annotated onto properties definitions.

It would seem possible to use `protogen.exe` to generate classes based on message-type defs ( `.proto` files ) that include `import` statements :

```
package MyPackage;                                                          

import "MyDerivedTypeProto.proto";                                                          

message MyMessage{                                                                          
    repeated MyDerivedType MyList = 1;                                                          
}
```

but the `import` statements apparently have no effect on the generated C# classes ( `.cs` files ) except to add a comment  :

```
// Generated from: MyMessageProto.proto
// Note: requires additional types generated from: MyDerivedType.proto
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"MyBaseTypeProto")]
[ProtoBuf.ProtoInclude(typeof(MyDerivedType), someFieldNumberUniqueInsideMyBaseType)]
public partial class MyBaseType: ProtoBuf.IExtensible { ... }

[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"MyDerivedTypeProto")] { ... }
public partial class MyDerivedType : MyBaseType, ProtoBuf.IExtensible

[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"MyMessageProto")]                                                                  
public partial class MyMessage : ProtoBuf.IExtensible                                           
{                                                                                               
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name = @"MyList", DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(null)]                                                  
    public List<MyDerivedType> MyList;
```

Should do it (untested, not by a suitable computer). The key addition is the `[ProtoInclude]` on the base-type. I removed `[Serializable]` because protobuf-net really doesn't care about that.

Comment: thanks Marc, but is it possible to somehow annotate the `.proto` file so that `protogen.exe` automatically generates the `ProtoInclude` attributes ?

Comment: @BaltoStar no, there is no syntax for that; however, you can put the sub-class attributes in a separate `partial` code file so you don't need to edit the generated one