# Struct is not a valid sub-type of interface in protobuf-net

Tags: c#, struct, protobuf-net

Is it possible to serialize interface-typed structs in protobuf-net, or does this only work for interface-typed classes?

I have a number of structs which I'd like to serialize, all of which implement an interface. I'm currently wrapping these in another struct (together with some meta data) in order to perform the serialization:

```
[ProtoContract]
public interface IData {}

[ProtoContract]
public struct MyData1 : IData { }
[ProtoContract]
public struct MyData2 : IData { }

[ProtoContract]
public struct SerializationStruct {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int SomeMetadata;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public IData Content
}
```

From reading other answers (e.g. [protobuf-net inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247513/protobuf-net-inheritance)), I should be able to add the types to the `RuntimeTypeModel` using `AddSubType` and then serialize an instance of `SerializationStruct`.

This works if I use classes for `MyData1` and `MyData2` but if I use structs (as above) I get the error:

`System.ArgumentException: MyData1 is not a valid sub-type of IData. Parameter name: derivedType`

when I attempt to add it to the model, like so:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(IData)].AddSubType(1, typeof(MyData1));
```

Comment: Where are you getting this exception? Can you create a [mre]? It sounds like you either did not correctly implement `IData` on `MyData1`, or you are referring to a different interface altogether where you get the exception.

Comment: @ConnorLow Thanks; the code posted should be sufficient to cause the problem, but I've added the specific line that causes the error to the question

Answer (score 1):

I "solved" this by switching to a different library to serialize ([MessagePack](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp)), which was able to handle this case using [Unions](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp#union). Coming back to protobuf-net, it seems that it also supports [discriminated unions](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/protobuf-net.Core/DiscriminatedUnion.cs), although I can't find any documentation of how, and I have not got any further.

I also looked at the code in protobuf-net that causes the specific error, and it appears (I think) to explicitly reject using structs as subtypes:

```
    private bool IsValidSubType(Type subType)
    {
        return subType is object && !subType.IsValueType
            && Type.IsAssignableFrom(subType);
    }
```

So I suppose the direct answer to my question is "no", but the practical answer is "there's probably a proper way to do it"